# Keypress combo for a secret entrance link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, keypress

I'd like a bit of code for my site, when I'm on a page, could be any page, but for this example we'll use a plain white page with 'herp' and no formatting on it. On this page, I'd like if the user then types 'derp' into the page, not into a text box, it will bring the user to the next page. Is this possible? Easy? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Heres a jQuery plugin that puts the konomi code in your website: https://github.com/eightbit/konami-code/blob/master/jquery.konami.js

Comment: This is possible, but a user can simply look at the source for "derp".

Comment: You could always obfuscate the keyword or move it server-side

Comment: How? (: Also, I can't make heads or tails of akonsu's answer D:

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it is possible, at least in Chrome if you attach a `keypress` handler to the `body`, you can keep track of the keys pressed and recognize when the needed word has been typed. Below is a sample code that attaches an event handler. I am not sure whether this is portable across browsers.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      $("body").keypress(function (event) {
        console.log(event);
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/pFHaSedMcxxHajywFJ0m

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this from scratch you would listen for key down and key up events. if you examine the event object from the key presses you will find some other hidden gems as well.

```
var body = document.querySelector('body'),
    downKeys={};

body.addEventListener(
    'keydown',
    keyDown
);

body.addEventListener(
    'keyup',
    keyUp
);

function keyDown(e){
    downKeys[e.keyCode]=true;
    testMagicCombo();
}

function keyUp(e){
    downKeys[e.keyCode]=false;
}

function testMagicCombo(){
    //you can add a lot more logic here to do more testing
    //but this is the gist of it.
    //the codes below are for ctrl+alt+shift+L (why L? why not?)
    //you can easily see all the key stats by logging the downKeys object
    if(downKeys[16]&&downKeys[17]&&downKeys[18]&&downKeys[76])
        console.log('unicorn greets you at magic entry');
}
```

Comment: you can easily find the key values for "derp" and use them instead but since I doubt that is the actual code you want I just used ctrl+alt+shift+L